# Systemd unit not failed after python process in pipe returns an exception

Tags: linux, pipe, systemd

We've got this systemd unit that launches two piped python processes in its `ExecStart=` directive. The unit is of type: `oneshot`, and when the first python process raises an exception somehow the unit is put back into an `inactive` state.

Below is our unit. It doesn't have an: `[Install]` section as we trigger it with a timer, or manually with: `systemctl start my-unit.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Connector
Documentation=Docs
StartLimitInterval=600
StartLimitBurst=3

[Service]
Type=oneshot
User=user
Group=group
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/dir

ExecStartPre=bash -c 'echo "Pre"'
ExecStart=bash -c 'python_1 | python_2'
ExecStartPost=bash -c 'echo "Post"'

KillMode=control-group
KillSignal=SIGTERM

StandardOutput=append:/home/user/dir/out.log
StandardError=append:/home/user/dir/err.log

TimeoutSec=21600

Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5
RemainAfterExit=false
```

From the docs systemd doesn't support pipes which is why we've been running the whole thing wrapped in a `bash -c '...'` command.

I know that the first python process has raised an Exception by looking at the logs in: `/home/user/dir/err.log`. This is the status of the unit after the first process has raised an exception:

```
● my-unit.service - Connector
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/my-unit.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2021-05-11 14:48:24 UTC; 12s ago
TriggeredBy: ● my-unit.timer
    Process: 108838 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/bash -c echo "Pre" (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 108839 ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c p1 | p2 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 108973 ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/bash -c echo "Post" (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 108839 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

May 11 14:48:21 ip-10-11-0-81 systemd[1]: Starting Connector...
May 11 14:48:24 ip-10-11-0-81 systemd[1]: connector-mavenlink.service: Succeeded.
May 11 14:48:24 ip-10-11-0-81 systemd[1]: Finished Connector mavenlink.
```

We're usually happy with this unit, it's the first time it's failing but we'd really like it to go in a `failed` state as we have observability tools in place to monitor that.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I think I fixed my own issue so I'll write this down here and probably leave that here for a bit before I close it. It does feel *a bit* hacky.

The fact that the `status code` of the `ExecStart=` directive is perceived as: `0` by systemd made me think of the `set -o pipefail` bash flag that we use to make a bash script understand pipe errors as an global error (poorly phrased, but I think that's the gist of it)

So I edited our unit to add the `-o pipefail` flag **in the `bash -c '...'` command** as such:

```
[Unit]
Description=Connector
Documentation=Docs
StartLimitInterval=600
StartLimitBurst=3

[Service]
Type=oneshot
User=user
Group=group
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/dir

ExecStartPre=bash -c 'echo "Pre"'
ExecStart=bash -c 'set -o pipefail && python_1 | python_2'
ExecStartPost=bash -c 'echo "Post"'

KillMode=control-group
KillSignal=SIGTERM

StandardOutput=append:/home/user/dir/out.log
StandardError=append:/home/user/dir/err.log

TimeoutSec=21600

Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5
RemainAfterExit=false
```

... which seemed to work: now when the first python process raises an Exception our unit is sent to a: `failed` state (after it's been restarted a few times as we've configured). Below is the updated `failed` status:

```
● my-unit.service - Connector
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/my-unit.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2021-05-11 15:01:28 UTC; 1s ago
TriggeredBy: ● my-unit.timer
       Docs: Docs
    Process: 109454 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/bash -c echo "Pre" (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 109463 ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c set -o pipefail && p1 | p2 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 109463 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 11 15:01:28 ip-10-11-0-81 systemd[1]: my-unit.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
May 11 15:01:28 ip-10-11-0-81 systemd[1]: Stopped Connector.
May 11 15:01:28 ip-10-11-0-81 systemd[1]: my-unit.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
May 11 15:01:28 ip-10-11-0-81 systemd[1]: my-unit.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 11 15:01:28 ip-10-11-0-81 systemd[1]: Failed to start Connector.
```